# Cloud function trigger from cloud workflow returns with http 500

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My Current GCP setup:

- Cloud scheduler
- Cloud workflow
- Cloud function (python 3.9) with 4G memory

Every hour scheduler triggers workflow API with arguments, In workflow one of the step is to call cloud function when it executes most of the times getting success but occasionally got error in workflow (HTTP server responded with error code 500) particular function log just shows (Function started and Function execution completed) no other function logs not sure what went wrong and how to debug this.

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Start to remove the useless part in your investigation. Cloud Scheduler and CLoud Workflow aren't the problem. Cloud Functions answer error 500 sometimes. Try to call directly the Cloud Functions and find what happens. Add trace in your functions, logs the parameters in entry, logs each functions line result to understand what is the runtime context when the error occurs. Check also the memory consumption of your Cloud Functions. You could have a memory leak that crash your function.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your reply. Yes you're right this issue nothing to do with scheduler and workflow. Just to explain the setup I've mentioned it. When the function invokes I've added log to print the arguments in the first line of my entry point but it was not even print those lines when this issue happens. That makes me not able to debug further.

Comment: Is it random, or only after several requests? (like a dozen). If so, try to reduce the memory to 2Gb and try again. If it occurs quicker, it's a memory leak

Comment: Yes it occurs randomly. currently I'm invoking 7 times per hour, For a day at least once I got 500 error. let me try to reduce the memory to 2Gb and try the same.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere After reducing memory from 4Gb to 2Gb, I didn't get 500 error for the last 2 days. I'm not sure why there is an error when we using 4Gb and cloud function supports memory at max 8Gb as of now. Is there a known issue (like memory leak as you mentioned) when we use memory more than 2Gb in cloud functions?

Comment: I don't know if there is a known issue. But with 4 or 8Gb of memory you have 2 CPUs, not only 1. It's also maybe an issue with your code (or underlying framework) that have issues when  multi CPUs is used. Anyway, if it solves your issue, and that you don't need 4Gb of memory, it's great :)